# Doctrine persist not updating existing records but trying to create a new one

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

In my application my domain model (aggregate) is different than a database models (entities), and because of that I have a separate aggregate and doctrine entity classes, and a mapper class which is building doctrine entity from aggregate and vise versa before getting/persisting, I'm doing it's directly in repository, like this:

```
  public function persist(Aggregate $aggregate): void
    {
        $this->entityManager->persist(
            $this->mapper->mapToDoctrineEntity($aggregate)
        );
    }

    public function get(AggregateId $id): Aggregate
    {
        /**
         * @var ?DoctrineEntity $entity
         */
        $entity = $this->entityManager->find(DoctrineEntity::class, $id->toInt());

        if (null === $entity) {
            throw new AggregateNotFoundException(sprintf('Aggregate [%d] not found', $id->toInt()));
        }

        return $this->mapper->mapToAggregate($entity);
    }
```

What mapper doing is simply creating new class of doctrine enitty or aggregate depends on what we need to create and populate with a data from entity/aggregate. All working fine with creating new records, but when I'm trying to update existing, doctrine does not see that entity with provided id already in the database and trying to insert it, which causing a duplication error. Is there a way to notify doctrine somehow that it's existing record????

Btw, before updating records I'm using repo method `get` to get existing record from database, but probably due to that transformation from doctrine entity to aggregate, doctrine loose tracking of that entity

Comment: You're mapping to a new entity, I presume. Have you thought of fetching that entity again before mapping, and if it exists, just modifying it instead of creating a new one?

Comment: Why use the entity manager and ORM if you are going to use your own mapping, different from Doctrine's? Just use the DBAL layer and manage it yourself.

Comment: that's probably true @yivi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom mapper on top of the doctrine seems not a good idea. Doctrine already is a data mapper and entities is meant to be a domain model.

But if you really need it you must keep entity that you got from repository, and update it on changes.

Comment: well, I need it because my domain model is more complex, has a bit different structure than database expects and builds/persist to different sources. And having aggregate to be also as a doctrine model require me to add additional proxy fields (for relations) which I do not need in domain. So I can have some kind of in memory cache in repo to hold all the doctrine entities I'm getting from database, and on `persist` map to them and update?